# Вывести сумму 2х чисел которая будет простым числом

Tags: c++

Есть массив от 1 до 500. В нём нужно разбить числа по парам, чтобы сумма этих чисел была простым числом. После первых 3х чисел которые выводит правильно, остальные идут непонятные(слишком огромные, то есть неравные простым).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;   
void amount(int array[], int &lenAr);    
int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a, length_array; 
    length_array = 500; 
    int *arr = new int[length_array];
    a = 1;    
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 
        arr[i] = a + i;
    }
        amount(arr, length_array); 
        system("pause"); 
        return 0;
}

void amount(int array[], int &lenAr)
{
    int *result = new int[500]; 
    int n, i; 
    int alpha, delta; 
    bool isPrime = true;                            
    for (int r = 0; r < 500; r++) {
        alpha = r;
        delta = alpha + 1;
        n = array[alpha] + array[delta];
        for (i = 2; i <= (sqrt(abs(n))); i++) {
            if (n%i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            result[r] = n;
        }
    }
    cout << "Все числа" << endl;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < lenAr; counter++)
    {
        cout << array[counter] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << "Простые числа" << endl;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 30; counter++)
    {
        cout << result[counter] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] array;
    delete[] result;
}
```

Comment: Можно пример чисел которые выводит?

Comment: @BogdanBida, 3  5  7  -842150451  -842150451 .... и дальше все одинаковые

Comment: И еще один вопрос, зачем вам переменная а? можно ведь просто вместо a + i; писать 1+ i;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все ошибки здесь

```
bool isPrime = true;                            
for (int r = 0; r < 500; r++) {  // 1
    alpha = r;
    delta = alpha + 1;           // 2
    n = array[alpha] + array[delta];
    for (i = 2; i <= (sqrt(abs(n))); i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;  // 3
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        result[r] = n;  // 4
    }
}
..........
delete[] array;  // 5
```

1. Вы передаете длину массива, но при этом запускаете цикл до 500
2. Вы прибавляете 1 к текущему индексу. При `alpha == 499` `delta == 500` выйдет за границы массива
3. Если Вы уже обнаружили, что число составное, зачем продолжать цикл дальше?
4. Вы записываете в массив `result` число, только если оно простое. При этом записываете его по индексу первого числа. Таким образом, куча элементов в массиве `result` у Вас непроинициализированы и содержат мусор. Этот мусор Вы и видите
5. Освобождать память, которую выделили не Вы - **очень** плохая практика

Вот, более-менее причесанный код

```c
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void amount(int array[], int lenAr);

int main(void) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
  int a, length_array;
  length_array = 500;
  int * arr = new int[length_array];
  for (int i = 1; i <= length_array; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }
  amount(arr, length_array);
  delete[] arr;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int val) {
  int middle = (int)sqrt(val);
  for (int i = 2; i <= middle; i++) {
    if (val % i == 0)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void amount(int array[], int lenAr) {
  vector<int> res = new int[lenAr];
  for (int i = 0; i < lenAr - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < lenAr; j++) {
      int n = array[i] + array[j];
      if (isPrime(n)) {
        res.push_back(n);
      }
    }
  }

  cout << "Все числа" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < lenAr; i++) {
    cout << array[i] << "  ";
  }

  cout << endl << "Простые числа" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
    cout << res[i] << "  ";
  }

  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, сразу после void amount, в int main(void) - ругается на идентификатор amount.

Comment: @AlexAlex Уберите `&` в предварительном объявлении `void amount(int array[], int &lenAr); `

Comment: спасибо что подсказали, помогло

Comment: @Alex а какой результат нужно из всего этого получить?

Comment: @J. Doe, вывод простых чисел, которые являются суммой 2х элементов масива

Comment: @Alex ну сейчас этот код выводит все числа от 1 до 500 и простые до 1000=), т.е даже если другие числа в массиве забить то будут только соседние проверяться, так и надо?

Comment: @J.Doe, он выводит сумму 2х элементов из первого массива, не пойму почему будут только соседние проверяться

Comment: @Alex потому, что проверяются только соседние. Это было в Вашем коде и это я повторил у себя. А что, нужны все пары?

Comment: @Alex в таком виде он выводит простые число до 1000 и все, если поменять массив будет что-то по другому

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Да, нужно было все пары, но я наверное и сам запутался, простите

Comment: @Alex Переписал на сумму пар

Comment: Я понял, спасибо вам за столько труда